# Way to check if customer has made a payment?

Tags: php, authorize.net

I'm trying to find a way of checking if a customer has clicked the final submit button to perform a transaction in PHP.

I need to send a second e-mail to different people when the customer makes a transaction, but as far as I can tell, there's no function or property to retrieve some sort of confirmation value.

I don't need to know if the payment went through or not, just if they clicked the last submit button, but the checkout page is hosted on Microsoft's servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. All of the payment APIs will return a status immediately. You just have to look for it and handle it in your code. How this is done will vary by API.
2. You can use [Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/)<sup>*</sup> which is similar to Paypal's IPN. Basically a script on your server will be notified of all payments.
3. Use the [Transaction Details API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/) and look for the transaction in your unsettled batches.

<sup>*</sup> I am the author of that article

Comment: The silent post seems like the easiest option, but the SIM script I'm using doesn't have a hidden field for the "x_response_code", will it work if I simply add it?

Comment: Look into [Relay Response](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Relay-Response-Basics-and-Troubleshooting/ba-p/9536) with SIM. That will get you everything that Silent Post provides (but obviously in a different way).

Comment: Just wanted to come back and thank you for the Relay Response reccomendation, worked like a charm.

Comment: @Rock2040 That's what I like to hear. :)